# OneDrive - Win10 vs. Mac/Win 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, onedrive

I have set up a Microsoft "Live" account, and one of the features is the "OneDrive" cloud storage. I've used this quite a bit from Windows 7, and it has worked flawlessly - I could open my files everywhere, even on a Mac.

Now with my new Windows 10 laptop, I don't have to install the OneDrive client software anymore - it's a built-in Win10 app. Sounds like a great improvement - but where on earth do my files go??

The files that I synchronize to OneDrive using the Win10 Onedrive app don't show up in the same place as my Windows 7 files, so on Windows 7 or a Mac, I cannot see those files...... or am I just looking in the wrong place?? What would be the *right* place to look for files synchronized by the Win10 Onedrive app??

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to view them from any computer, have you tried forcing a sync from both devices? That being the PC that you added the files from and the PC that you're looking for the files on.